Issue while installing requirement.txt : - Saleor
I cloned Saleor (https://github.com/saleor/saleor) from GitHub and enabled a virtual environment. When I try to install the requirements.txt file, I'm getting an error like this:
Collecting suds-jurko>=0.6
  Using cached suds-jurko-0.6.zip (255 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
 
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      error in suds-jurko setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
      [end of output]
 
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed


Which requirements.txt are you trying to install? There is none in the saleor repository.

If you haven't written any code on your own, but face a problem with existing software, please report this in their issue tracker

As already said in comments, there is no requirements.txt file in Saleor.
You need to use poetry to install dependencies:
https://docs.saleor.io/docs/3.x/developer/community/contributing#managing-dependencies
Or follow the guide:
https://docs.saleor.io/docs/3.x/setup/docker-compose
